# Process bulk actions with POST method - WP_List_Table

Tags: wp-list-table

I want to avoid to execute the bulk action again if someone reloads the page accidentally. If the bulk actions are processed with method POST a warning will be launched at least.

Could be this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was so simple. In order to process bulk actions with post method I should generate the table as follows:

```
<form id="table-filter" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>" />
    <?php $wc_rev_ga_trans->display(); ?>
</form>
```